# Sort and filter IQueryable in datagridview

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have a query made using linq to SQL which result will be shown in a datagridview with sorting and filtering options.

```
public IQueryable RegresaDepositosBancarios()
        {
            var depositos = from d in context.depositos_bancarios
                            where d.Aplicado == false
                            orderby d.FechaDeposito ascending
                            select new
                            {
                                d.IDDeposito,
                                d.cuentas_bancarias.Nombre,
                                d.Monto,
                                d.FechaDeposito,
                                d.Observaciones
                            };
            return depositos    ;
        }
```

Later in my code I set the datasource to use previous result.

```
var depositos = operaciones.RegresaDepositosBancarios();
dataGrid_depositos.DataSource = depositos;
```

As you can see I'm returning and IQueryable of anonymous type and I can't perform sorting or filtering over this. I read that you can implement a custom function to convert IQueryable to DataView and then use the RowFilter property, is this the more efficient way of doing it? Could be better to return other type in my function?

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487870/allow-user-to-sort-columns-from-a-linq-query-in-a-datagridview

Comment: So which method (described in link given) do you think is more suitable in my case? SortableBindingList or converting result to DataTable?

Comment: I must admit that i've never used DataGridView with LINQ as DataSource. But both methods seem to have pros and cons, the one might be faster and typesafe, the other slower(using Reflection) but easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the return type from `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, then you can do something like:

```
 var over100 = RegresaDepositosBancarios()
    .Where(d => d.Monto > 100);
```

I think you could also code it this way (however I don't normally use `from` so am not sure)

```
 var over100 = from d in RegresaDepositosBancarios()
    where d.Montho > 100;
```

Here's a test program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
public class Class1
{
    public int A;
    public int B;
}

public class Test
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Build()
    {
        var list = new List<Class1>();
        list.Add(new Class1() { A = 10, B = 100 });
        list.Add(new Class1() { A = 200, B = 2000 });

        return list
            .OrderBy(e => e.B)
            .Select(e => new { A1 = e.A, B2 = e.B });
    }

    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> Filter()
    {
        return Build()
            .Where(e => e.A1 > 100);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (dynamic e in Filter())
            Console.WriteLine("A1={0}, B2={1}", e.A1, e.B2);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I get the following with your answer: "An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation"

Comment: Sorry my fault for not testing.  Change `IQueryable<dynamic>` to `IEnumerable<dynamic>'.  I've added a test program to the answer.

Comment: After some research I think your code is not appropiated to my particular case since it uses IEnumerable and my research stated that it's better to use IQueryable when querying a database. Do you think using a generic list<t> is a good idea?

Comment: Yes, a List<T> is a much better way to go.  However, your question was about using an anonymous class not a about best practices or IEnumerable vs IQueryable.